# Delphi TObject position change

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to make a universal function that I can apply to numerous different components; however, I cannot just do

```
TObject.Position
```

It asks that I do

```
TButton(TObject).Position
```

This means that I would have to do

```
if TObject is TButton then
    TButton(TObject).position...
if TObject is TLabel then
    TLabel(TObject).position...
```

Is there a way to make it work as:

```
TObject.position
```

So that the function can be as universal as possible and not cluttered with switch/if statements...?

Here is what I have:

```
procedure TForm3.gestureObj(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if EventInfo.GestureID = igiPan then
    handlePan(EventInfo, Sender);
end;

procedure TForm3.handlePan(EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; sender: TObject);
var
  item: TControl;
begin

  item:= TControl(TObject);
end;
```

Doing it like this gives me an access violation when I try to move do item.position, I suspect this is because it is no TControl?

Comment: Just `TControl(YourControlInstance).Position := ...` because [`Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Position) property is introduced by the `TControl` class and so it's common for all its descendants.

Comment: @TLama if `YourControlInstance` was descended from `TControl` then `YourControlInstance.Position` would work. At the very least a checked cast with `as` would be prudent. Or perhaps a single `if YourControlInstance is TControl then ....`

Comment: @David, my mistake. I wanted to write `YourObjectInstance` since it seems that OP passes a `TObject` instance (at least that's how I get it). And OP seems to know how to test whether the instance is of certain class...

Comment: @TLama Final sentence of my comment, inspired by yours, seems to be the answer. Feel free to write it up as such.

Comment: Added some more info, I tried what you guys suggested and it gave me an  access violation.

Comment: I don't see any point where you test what the object is. Also, `TControl(TObject)` is wrong. You want to cast a type to an instance?! In fact I cannot see a single part of your question where you cast an instance. And I don't know why you ignore the advice to use checked casts. Learn about the `is` and `as` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use:

```
sender as TControl
```